# SQL Error: ORA-01403: no data found

Tags: oracle

when fire update query

```
update JISPBILCORBILLINGPRD501.TBLMACCOUNTADDRESS set Address1='NehateSir',stateid='STT0002' where accountid='ACC000000068'
```

that time this error occurs

```
Error starting at line 4 in command:
update JISPBILCORBILLINGPRD501.TBLMACCOUNTADDRESS set Address1='NehateSir',stateid='STT0002' where accountid='ACC000000068'
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "WOM.TRGBILLINGADDRESS", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'WOM.TRGBILLINGADDRESS'
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

bellow is trigger code

```
create or replace
TRIGGER TRGBILLINGADDRESS AFTER
  INSERT OR
  DELETE OR
  UPDATE ON jispbilcorbillingprd501.TBLMACCOUNTADDRESS FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
  add1 varchar2(200) ;
  add2 varchar2(200);
  cityid varchar2(200);
  stateid varchar2(200);
  pincd varchar2(200);
  parlcid varchar2(12);
  BEGIN
    select endbcirclename into parlcid from jispbilcorbillingprd501.tblmaccountprofile where accountid =:NEW.accountid;
    SELECT address1,
      address2,
      city_id,
      state_id,
      pincode
    INTO add1,
      add2,
      cityid,
      stateid,
      pincd
    FROM wom.tbltaddress ta
    WHERE ta.ID IN
      (SELECT vbac.billing_address_id
      FROM wom.vw_billaddresschange vbac,
        wom.tbltaddress ita
      WHERE vbac.billing_address_id = ita.ID
      AND vbac.lcid                 = parlcid
      );
    IF
    add1 = :new.address1 AND add2 = :new.address2 AND cityid = :new.cityid AND stateid = :new.stateid
    AND pincd = :new.zip THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Address Already Exist in tbltaddress table');
    ELSE
      UPDATE wom.tbltaddress ta
      SET ta.address1 = :new.address1,
        ta.address2   = :new.address2,
        ta.city_id    = :new.cityid,
        ta.country_id = 'CTR0001',
        ta.state_id   = :new.stateid,
        ta.pincode    = :new.zip
      WHERE ta.ID    IN
        (SELECT vbac.billing_address_id
        FROM wom.vw_billaddresschange vbac,
          wom.tbltaddress ita
        WHERE vbac.billing_address_id = ita.ID
        AND vbac.lcid                 = parlcid
        );
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 10):

This query:

```
SELECT address1,
  address2,
  city_id,
  state_id,
  pincode
INTO add1,
  add2,
  cityid,
  stateid,
  pincd
FROM wom.tbltaddress ta
WHERE ta.ID IN
  (SELECT vbac.billing_address_id
  FROM wom.vw_billaddresschange vbac,
    wom.tbltaddress ita
  WHERE vbac.billing_address_id = ita.ID
  AND vbac.lcid                 = parlcid
  );
```

does not return anything which causes an exception in `PL/SQL`.

You should catch this exception:

```
BEGIN
        SELECT  address1,
                address2,
                city_id,
                state_id,
                pincode
        INTO    add1,
                add2,
                cityid,
                stateid,
                pincd
        FROM    wom.tbltaddress ta
        WHERE   ta.ID IN
                (
                SELECT  vbac.billing_address_id
                FROM    wom.vw_billaddresschange vbac,
                        wom.tbltaddress ita
                WHERE   vbac.billing_address_id = ita.ID
                        AND vbac.lcid = parlcid
                );
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
        NULL; -- or do anything useful
END;
```

If you are using `Oracle 9i` or above, use `MERGE` statement instead of implementing `UPSERT` in a trigger.

Comment: And about the MERGE statement, my own question can probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863960/could-somebody-explain-what-the-merge-statement-really-does-in-oracle

Answer (score -2):

Watch out below example

```
BEGIN
    SELECT nvl(COUNT(1),0),nvl(MIN(COST),0),DOCUMENTPARTID INTO l_itemexistCount,l_contractcost,l_docpartid 
    FROM CONTRACTPRICE WHERE RESELLERID= l_companyid AND CONTRACTID=l_contractid AND 
    MANUFACTURERPART = l_manufacturerpart and status = 0 AND DOCUMENTPARTID=l_docpartid AND ROWNUM <=1  
    GROUP BY DOCUMENTPARTID ORDER BY MIN(COST) DESC;
    IF nvl(l_itemexistCount,0) > 0 THEN
        l_staticStr4 := l_staticStr4 || '\n(' || l_count || ') - ' || l_manufacturerpart || ' [$' || l_contractcost||']';
        p_paramout:=p_paramout||','||l_docpartid;
        l_count:= l_count + 1;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
    NULL; -- or do anything useful
END;
```

Comment: So, why does this answer the question?