# How to update a table using inner join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables Emp & Dept.

```
SQL> select * from emp where rownum<4;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR        SAL     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902        800
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698       1600
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698       1250

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME           LOC                  EMPNO
---------- --------------- --------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING      NEW YORK              7369
        20 RESEARCH        DALLAS                7499
        30 SALES           CHICAGO               7521
        40 OPERATIONS      BOSTON
```

i want to update deptno of emp which should be same as deptno of dept table & where empno of dept should be equal to empno of emp;        In short i want to update dept using inner join operation with emp;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, the canonical way to do it is the `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO emp e
USING dept d
   ON (d.empno = e.empno)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET e.deptno = d.deptno
```

However the above will not work if you are using Oracle 9 (see below), or if there are domain index on your tables (Oracle Text for instance)

I [asked a question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863960/could-somebody-explain-what-the-merge-statement-really-does-in-oracle) about what MERGE statements do.

It is necessary that each row of `e` be connected by the join condition (`ON` section) to none or exactly 1 row of `d`, otherwise you'll get ORA-30926 “Unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables”.

Rows of `e` not connected to any department get unchanged, rows of `d` not connected to any employee could be used for `INSERTS` (and in Oracle 9 **must** be used in a  `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(cols) VALUES(...)` clause; if you're using Oracle 9 then this answer is not suitable for you).

Another option, but subject to the same underlying restrictions:

```
UPDATE (SELECT e.deptno edeptno, d.deptno ddeptno
          FROM emp e, dept d
         WHERE e.empno = d.empno)
   SET edeptno = ddeptno
```

Or

```
UPDATE emp
   SET deptno = ( SELECT deptno FROM dept WHERE empno = emp.empno )
 WHERE empno IN ( SELECT empno FROM dept )
```

As you can see solutions are numerous but subject to constraints.

Comment: So, what did you choose among those three and which one did you prefer?

Answer (score 2):

```
Update emp e 
set deptno = ( select DEPTNO from dept d where d.empno = e.empno )
```

Will work as long as the EMPNO in DEPT is unique.

Edit - 
As pointed out, this will fail if EMPNO is not there.

The very HACKY fix to this is,

> Update emp e
>
> set deptno = (
>
> ```
>          SELECT RESULT FROM (
>           select DEPTNO RESULT from dept d where d.empno = e.empno
>            UNION ALL 
>            select NULL from DUAL 
>            ORDER BY 1
>            ) WHERE ROWNUM < 2
>          )
> ```

Comment: Yes. But will fail if an employee cannot be found in dept.

Comment: `UNION ALL select null from dual order by 1` should include `NULLS LAST`, but even simpler is `RIGHT JOIN dual ON 1 = 1`