# When doing a MERGE in Oracle SQL, how can I update rows that aren't matched in the SOURCE?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

I have a `main` database and a `report` database, and I need to sync a table from `main` into `report`.

However, when an item gets deleted in the `main` database, I only want to set an `IsDeleted` flag in the `report` database.

What is an elegant way to do this?

I'm currently using a MERGE statement, like this:

```
MERGE INTO report.TEST target
USING (SELECT * FROM main.TEST) source
   ON (target.ID = source.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET (target... = source...)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (...) VALUES (source...)
;
```

The `WHEN NOT MATCHED` statement gives me all NEW values from `main`, but I also want to update all OLD values from `report`.

I'm using Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: With which values do you want to update `main.test`? Where would you get them from?

Comment: If the row is deleted from `main.test`, then the corresponding `report.test` row will be unmatched.  I want to set the `report.test.IsDeleted` flag for all unmatched rows.

Comment: I don't think that will be possible as the result of the underlying JOIN (`using (...)`) will not contain that row. So where should that data come from?

Comment: So, is `MERGE` similar to an `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?  I guess I was hoping that  might have a `FULL OUTER JOIN` option.

Comment: I think that SQL Server 2008 has a `WHEN NOT MATCHED ON SOURCE` clause that does a `FULL OUTER JOIN`!  I can't find much documentation on it, but I tried it in Oracle with no success, so I guess I'll look at other options.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it with a separate UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE report.TEST target
SET    is Deleted = 'Y'
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   main.TEST source
                   WHERE  source.ID = target.ID);
```

I don't know of any way to integrate this into your MERGE statement.

Comment: It seems weird that I can't do this with MERGE.  I'll consider this answer.

Comment: Would it be any more "elegant"/efficient if I did an `OUTER JOIN`, and updated where `main.test is null`?

Comment: There's a related question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863960/could-somebody-explain-what-the-merge-statement-really-does-in-oracle, I think it'll do an outer join, not a full outer join, so I don't think what you've suggested will work.

Comment: Thank you so much, that link was very helpful  What I learned: if `MERGE` only has `WHEN MATCHED THEN`, it uses a regular `JOIN`.  If there's a `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN`, it uses a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  Now, I'm wishing for a feature such as `WHEN NOT MATCHED ON SOURCE THEN`, which will do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  But this might only exist for SQL Server, not Oracle.

Answer (score 6):

The following answer is to **merge data into same table**

```
MERGE INTO YOUR_TABLE d
USING (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL) m
    ON ( d.USER_ID = '123' AND d.USER_NAME= 'itszaif') 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ( d.USERS_ID, d.USER_NAME)
        VALUES ('123','itszaif');
```

This command checks if `USER_ID` and `USER_NAME` are matched, if not matched then it will insert.

Answer (score 5):

```
MERGE INTO target
USING
(
    --Source data
    SELECT id, some_value, 0 deleteMe FROM source
    --And anything that has been deleted from the source
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, null some_value, 1 deleteMe
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id FROM target
        MINUS
        SELECT id FROM source
    )
) source
   ON (target.ID = source.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    --Requires a lot of ugly CASE statements, to prevent updating deleted data
    UPDATE SET target.some_value =
        CASE WHEN deleteMe=1 THEN target.some_value ELSE source.some_value end
    ,isDeleted = deleteMe
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, some_value, isDeleted) VALUES (source.id, source.some_value, 0)

--Test data
create table target as
select 1 ID, 'old value 1' some_value, 0 isDeleted from dual union all
select 2 ID, 'old value 2' some_value, 0 isDeleted from dual;

create table source as
select 1 ID, 'new value 1' some_value, 0 isDeleted from dual union all
select 3 ID, 'new value 3' some_value, 0 isDeleted from dual;


--Results:
select * from target;

ID  SOME_VALUE   ISDELETED
1   new value 1  0
2   old value 2  1
3   new value 3  0
```

Comment: Thanks for being creative!  I'm not gonna do this, but it does get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
merge into x as target using y as Source on target.ID = Source.ID
when not matched by target then insert
when matched then update
when not matched by source and target.ID is not null then
update whatevercolumn = 'isdeleted' ;
```

Comment: where did you found this syntax? (`by target`)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for ... however, as @FlorinGhita said, where did you find this syntax?  Is this MS SQL syntax?

Comment: -1 as this is [SQL Server merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) syntax not [Oracle merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

Comment: Just for everyone's reference, this is a good answer, but `not matched by target` and `not matched by source` is a feature only supported by MS SQL Server.  This feature would solve my problem, so I wish Oracle SQL supported it.